# No se como alternar la suma y la resta y que me de el resultado correspondiente

Tags: c#, bucle-for

Se supone que debe ir alternando la suma y la resta de la siguiente manera "Serie alternada = 1 – 1/2 + 1/3 – 1/4 + 1/5 – 1/6 + 1/7 – 1/8 +...hasta llegar al 1/50"

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double num = 1;
        double sumatoria = 0;
        Console.Write("Sumatoria Alternada = 1 ");
        for (int i = 2; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(num+ "/" +i+ " ");

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sumatoria = " + sumatoria);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Usa alguna variable que te indique si tu iteración tiene que hacer una suma o una resta, y que cambie al valor opuesto al final de la iteración. Por ejemplo, un booleano, o un double con valor 1 y -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta serie es una secuencia de uno a cincuenta, alternando positivos y negativos, siendo los primeros impares y los segundos pares, tienes un par de opciones para programar eso.

1. Bucle `for`:

   ```
   double sumatoria = 0;

   for (double denominador = 1; denominador != 51; ++denominador)
   {
       sumatoria += (1.0 / (denominador % 2 == 0 ? -denominador : denominador));
   }
   ```
2. Sentencia LinQ:

   ```
   double sumatoria = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Sum(n => 1.0 / (n % 2 == 0? -n : n));
   ```